# Non-Linear data fitting for kinetic data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, model-fitting, chemistry

[image: Langmuir Hinshelwood Model Image]

[Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-M1DpuI4XNfSJktVG_ibzy-RzSAeUSIj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116419220787995800483&rtpof=true&sd=true)

*Update: I modified the code after the suggestions of @jlandercy. Further, the code now solves a differential equation shown below to optimize the flow of my product gas. Sample data is updated.

[image: PFR differential equation optimized]

I am trying to fit a two-site Langmuir Hinshelwood model which I derived, (basically, rate as a function of pressures of reactants and products) to my experimental data. The model converges, but changing the initial parameters can make a stark difference. The problem is those parameters matter for my analysis. Since I am comparing different models, the model vs experiment % fit depends on these parameters (K1, K2 ...).

I wanted to know if there is any other method to check that a particular set of parameters are better than the others (obviously a particular combination will give a slightly better-fit percentage, but that, in my opinion, may not the deciding criteria). The MSE landscape calculation, as suggested by @jlandercy, has been useful in understanding the convexity relationship between different parameters, however, I could not extract more information from them to move ahead and fix my K parameters.

P.S.: The other models are way simpler, in terms of mathematics, than this model. So, if I this is well understood, I should be able to compare the models with decent parameter accuracy.
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

# Step 1: Read experimental data

data1 = pd.read_excel("Local address of file")

# Extract the partial pressures (A, B, C) and the reaction rate
pp = data1.iloc[:49, 2:5].values
TT = data1.iloc[:49, 16].values
rr = data1.iloc[:49, 17].values
F0 = data1.iloc[:49, 5:10].values
W = data1.iloc[:49, 15].values
FF = data1.iloc[:49, 10:15].values

data = np.hstack((pp, F0, FF, W.reshape(-1,1), TT.reshape(-1,1)))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Kinetic:
    
    """Langmuir-Hinshelwood Two-Site Kinetic Model Solver"""
    
    R = 8.314              # J/mol.K
    Ea = 45000  # J/mol  
    theta_g = [0.9, 0.1]    # 1
    
    w = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    
    @staticmethod
    def k3(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Arrhenius estimation for k3"""
        pA, pB, pC, F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h, FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h, mg, T = data
        return k0 * np.exp(-Kinetic.Ea / (Kinetic.R * T))

    @staticmethod
    def s(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Partial kinetic rate"""
        pA, pB, pC, F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h, FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h, mg, T = data
        
        #Calculating gas pressures at every position of PFR reactor
        pA_t = flow[0] / np.sum(flow)
        pB_t = flow[1] / np.sum(flow)
        pC_t = flow[2] / np.sum(flow)
        
        k3 = Kinetic.k3(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0)
        return (K1 * K2 * k3 / k4) * pA_t * pB_t

    @staticmethod
    def equation(x, y, C, s):
        return 1/(1 + C + np.sqrt(s*y/x)) - x
    
    @staticmethod
    def system(theta, flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Isothermal coverages system"""
        pA, pB, pC, F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h, FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h, mg, T = data
        t0, t1 = theta
        s = Kinetic.s(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0)
        
        pA_t = flow[0] / np.sum(flow)
        pB_t = flow[1] / np.sum(flow)
        pC_t = flow[2] / np.sum(flow)
        
        C0 = K2 * pB_t
        C1 = K1 * pA_t + pC_t / K5
        return np.array([
            Kinetic.equation(t0, t1, C0, s),
            Kinetic.equation(t1, t0, C1, s),
        ])

    @staticmethod
    def _theta(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Single Isothermal coverages"""
        solution = fsolve(
            Kinetic.system,
            Kinetic.theta_g,
            args=(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0),
            full_output=False
        )
        if not(all((solution >= 0) & (solution <= 1.0))):
            raise ValueError("Theta are not constrained to domain: %s" % solution)
        return solution

    @staticmethod
    def theta(flow, data, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Isothermal coverages"""
        return np.apply_along_axis(Kinetic._theta, 0, flow, data, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)

    @staticmethod
    def r1(flow, w, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Global kinetic rate"""
        pA, pB, pC, F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h, FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h, mg, T = data
         
        pA_t = flow[0] / np.sum(flow)
        pB_t = flow[1] / np.sum(flow)
        pC_t = flow[2] / np.sum(flow)

        #print(pA)
        
        k3 = Kinetic.k3(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0)
        t0, t1 = Kinetic.theta(flow, data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0)
        v=np.array([-1,-1, 1, 0, 0])
        #v = v[:, np.newaxis]  # Convert v to a 2D array with shape (5, 1)
        return ((K1 * K2 * k3) * pA_t * pB_t * t0 * t1) * v
        

    @staticmethod
    def dFdm(data, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0):
        """Global kinetic rate"""
        residual =[]
        sq=[]
        for i in data:
            pA, pB, pC, F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h, FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h, mg, T = i
            F0 = np.array([F0_a, F0_b, F0_c, F0_ar, F0_h])
            FF = np.array([FF_a, FF_b, FF_c, FF_ar, FF_h]) # Final Experimental flows
            
            flow = odeint(Kinetic.r1, F0, Kinetic.w, args = (i, K1, K2, k4, K5, k0))
            flow_pred = flow[-1,2]  # Predicted final model flows
            res = (flow_pred - FF_c)*1000
            residual.append(res)
        return residual

bounds=((0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf))
initial_guesses = [8, 8, 50, 16, 6]
result = least_squares(lambda k: Kinetic.dFdm(data, *k), x0=initial_guesses, bounds=bounds, ftol=1e-14)

K1_fit, K2_fit, k4_fit, K5_fit, k0_fit = result.x
print(K1_fit, K2_fit, k4_fit, K5_fit, k0_fit)
```

Comment: This might be better suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you post the ODE system of your model to check it against your code. Also could you publish some trial dataset (synthetic one is fine, if you don't want to disclose experimental data). Don't use screenshots, copy paste it in a CSV format. Cheers

Comment: Looks like Langmuir Isotherm models. One challenge you have is that your have over determined constants that may prevent the fitting procedure to converge. Additionally, you must check twice your constants to track dimensional issues if any. Update your post with the exact model, I'll have a check on it.

Comment: There is at least a convergence problem in your theta estimation, with given parameters and plausible pressure it does not converge hence preventing the rest of fitting procedure to be meaningful. I'll wait for your update.

Comment: @jlandercy thanks for the replies. The model is Langmuir one, you are right. It converges too, but probably not finding the global optima, giving some fit parameters quite away from initial guesses. Regarding theta estimation, I am not sure if there is any alternative way to solve. The theta values, at the end of the optimization, are between 0 and 1, which is what I needed.
I am also aware that I have very few data points currently to fit, but just wanted to check the logic while I collect the kinetic data.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Indeed thetas are constrained on `(0, 1)` but you must take care of system solving convergence because clamping using `max(min)` as you did is not a proper way to solve the system. If you try to solve it numerically with ad hoc optimization procedures you will see that the problem is somehow ill-posed and need to be reworked to ensure proper convergence. Cheers

Comment: Sure, thanks for the reply! I understand what you re saying. Could you suggest a better way to do it? I was thinking to start with a guess and let the values converge, not constraining between 0 and 1, and then check the output array of values.
However, apart from theta values, is this fitting approach right for the model.  Just that it is a non-linear problem, and I am not very sure how to check the accuracy of results. Thanks

Comment: Just updated the code @jlandercy. Tried to use fsolve to solve for theta star and theta prime. I still have high errors, but that is also because it is less data points perhaps. Anyway, please let me know if the model works better now. The only issue I have with fit parameters is the value of K2 (which stops at the lower bound (>0 always), but the value should be quite high, similar to my initial guess). All other fit parameters are in range.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

It's not possible to tell with your 11 points if they fits properly the proposed model. The model converges but with high errors on parameters and high sensitivity w.r.t. initial guess. So at this point don't trust the output of the model.

But it is possible to show that with at least 50 points spanning the variable space the model converges towards expected parameters with decent precision and the process is stable with reasonable error term on data.

It means that you either need to collect more points with ad hoc precision or your kinetic may not reasonably follow the proposed model.

#### Procedure

Let's break down the global task into smaller tasks. To solve the kinetic we need to address:

- Non linear system of equations solving with domain constraints (partial coverages lie between 0 and 1):

  - Ensure solution existence and uniqueness (see abacus)
  - Educated guess for initial parameters (convergence and solution selection)
- Non linear least squares (NLLS) solving with domain constraints (chemical constants are positive definite):

  - Ensure reasonable MSE landscape to make global minimum reachable (enough points with bearable errors over variable space)
  - Make procedure robust against initial parameters variation
  - Parameters normalization and decoupling (if necessary)

In both task we need to ensure convergence towards global minimum or desired solution in addition of numerical stability.

The `scipy` package is the good companion to solve this class of optimization problems using:

- [`optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) for non linear equations system;
- [`optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) fon NLLS adjustment.

##### Solver

Below a class handling this problem in details:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Kinetic:
    
    """Langmuir-Hinshelwood Two-Site Kinetic Model Solver"""
    
    R = 8.314              # J/mol.K
    Ea = 37000             # J/mol
    T = 473.15             # K
    theta_ = [0.9, 0.9]    # 1
    
    @staticmethod
    def k3(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Arrhenius estimation for k3"""
        return k0*np.exp(-Kinetic.Ea/(Kinetic.R*Kinetic.T))

    @staticmethod
    def s(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Partial kinetic rate"""
        pA, pB, pC = p
        k3 = Kinetic.k3(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)
        return (k1*k2*k3/k4)*pA*pB
    
    @staticmethod
    def equation(x, y, C, s):
        return 1/(1 + C + np.sqrt(s*y/x)) - x
    
    @staticmethod
    def isopleth(x, y, s):
        return (x + np.sqrt(s*x*y) - 1)/x
    
    @staticmethod
    def system(theta, p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Isothermal coverages system"""
        pA, pB, pC = p
        t0, t1 = theta
        s = Kinetic.s(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)
        C0 = k2*pB
        C1 = k1*pA + pC/k5
        return np.array([
            Kinetic.equation(t0, t1, C0, s),
            Kinetic.equation(t1, t0, C1, s),
        ])
    
    @staticmethod
    def _theta(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Single Isothermal coverages"""
        solution = optimize.fsolve(
            Kinetic.system,
            Kinetic.theta_,
            args=(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0),
            full_output=False
        )
        if not(all((solution >= 0.) & (solution <= 1.0))):
            raise ValueError("Theta are not constrained to domain: %s" % solution)
        return solution
    
    @staticmethod
    def theta(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Isothermal coverages"""
        return np.apply_along_axis(Kinetic._theta, 0, p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)
    
    @staticmethod
    def r(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0):
        """Global kinetic rate"""
        pA, pB, pC = p
        k3 = Kinetic.k3(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)
        t0, t1 = Kinetic.theta(p, k1, k2, k4, k5, k0)
        return (k1*k2*k3)*pA*pB*t0*t1
    
    @staticmethod
    def solve(p, r, *k):
        """Global kinetic constants adjustment"""
        return optimize.curve_fit(
            Kinetic.r, p.T, r, p0=k,
            bounds=((0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)),
            method="trf",
            gtol=1e-10,
            full_output=True
        )
    
    @staticmethod
    def abaque(s, C=None):
        
        lin = np.linspace(0.0001, 1.1, 200)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(lin, lin)
        if C is None:
            C = np.arange(0, 26, 1)
        
        Cx = Kinetic.isopleth(X, Y, s)
        Cy = Kinetic.isopleth(Y, X, s)
      
        fig, axe = plt.subplots()
        xlabels = axe.contour(X, Y, Cx, C, cmap="jet")
        axe.clabel(xlabels, xlabels.levels, inline=True, fontsize=7)
        ylabels = axe.contour(X, Y, Cy, C, cmap="jet")
        axe.clabel(ylabels, ylabels.levels, inline=True, fontsize=7)
        axe.set_title("Isothemal Coverages System\nConstant Isopleths ($s={}$)".format(s))
        axe.set_xlabel(r"Partial Coverage, $\theta_0$ [-]")
        axe.set_ylabel(r"Partial Coverage, $\theta_1$ [-]")
        axe.set_aspect("equal")
        axe.set_xlim([0, 1.1])
        axe.set_ylim([0, 1.1])
        axe.grid()
        
        return axe
```

Notice it uses the TRF solver instead of the default [LM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) solver to ensure parameters constraints are enforced. With your dataset, using LM return negative parameters for some initial guesses.

#### Experimental dataset

If we check the model against your experimental dataset with proposed initial guess:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
p = df.filter(regex="p").values
r = df["rate"].values

Kinetic.solve(p, r, 5, 1e5, 50, 10, 100)
```

We get the following adjustment:

```
(array([1.39075854e-01, 2.15668993e+03, 1.16513471e+00, 2.69648513e-01,
        2.64057386e+00]),
 array([[ 1.48622028e+03, -6.20830186e+06,  2.86587881e+05,
          1.03973854e+02, -2.89149484e+04],
        [-6.20830186e+06,  1.73740772e+12, -3.36688691e+09,
          9.40415116e+06,  1.17499454e+08],
        [ 2.86587881e+05, -3.36688691e+09,  5.84376597e+07,
          5.50069835e+03, -5.57235249e+06],
        [ 1.03973854e+02,  9.40415116e+06,  5.50069835e+03,
          8.40397226e+01, -2.04455154e+03],
        [-2.89149484e+04,  1.17499454e+08, -5.57235249e+06,
         -2.04455154e+03,  5.62563731e+05]]),
 {'nfev': 10,
  'fvec': array([ 1.63900711e-06,  1.66564630e-06,  1.55523211e-06,  2.83708013e-06,
          2.40778598e-06,  2.85927736e-06,  3.37890387e-08, -1.19231145e-06,
         -4.03211541e-07, -2.37714019e-06, -3.98891395e-06])},
 '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.',
 1)
```

The adjustment converges but it is definitely not satisfying: errors are several decade higher than parameters.

In addition, changing the initial guess returns drastically different parameters meaning the MSE landscape is not properly shaped to ensure stable convergence.

Both symptoms are generally an evidence against the lack of data and/or too high errors on regressed variable. But indeed it can be also bad model selection and bad implementation, hence the need to analyze procedure sensitivity.

#### Synthetic dataset

Let's build a synthetic dataset spanning the variable space with normal noise on it:

```
plin = np.linspace(0.1, 0.3, 5)
PA, PB, PC = np.meshgrid(plin, plin, plin)

P = np.vstack([
    PA.flatten(), PB.flatten(), PC.flatten()
]).T

R = Kinetic.r(P.T, 5, 1e5, 50, 10, 100)
R += np.random.randn(R.shape[0])*1e-7
```

Following calls decently converge towards the expected parameters with fair errors:

```
Kinetic.solve(P, R, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Kinetic.solve(P, R, 1e2, 1e2, 1e2, 1e2, 1e2)
Kinetic.solve(P, R, 1e4, 1e4, 1e4, 1e4, 1e4)

(array([4.99738701e+00, 1.02579705e+05, 4.74129338e+01, 9.98744998e+00,
        1.00075578e+02]),
 array([[ 8.22367638e-06,  8.36365990e-02,  8.07407481e-03,
         -5.91768686e-07, -2.40408987e-04],
        [ 8.36365990e-02,  8.97492687e+07,  8.22981373e+01,
         -3.59165834e-04, -7.40000336e+00],
        [ 8.07407481e-03,  8.22981373e+01,  7.94766011e+00,
         -1.77033582e-04, -2.36480247e-01],
        [-5.91768686e-07, -3.59165834e-04, -1.77033582e-04,
          4.05361075e-05,  5.41574698e-06],
        [-2.40408987e-04, -7.40000336e+00, -2.36480247e-01,
          5.41574698e-06,  7.03833667e-03]]),
 {'nfev': 175,
  'fvec': array([ 1.63383888e-07, -4.98390311e-08, -3.59565336e-08,  6.62435527e-08,
         -7.48972275e-08, -9.51285315e-08,  8.58923659e-10, -9.53560561e-08,
          1.92097574e-07,  1.72359976e-08,  1.06487677e-07, -8.48179470e-08,
          ...
          7.36713698e-08, -4.52283602e-08,  1.21064513e-07, -1.40410586e-08,
         -8.25508331e-08])},
 '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.',
 1)
```

Parameters are close to expected values and errors on parameters are low, leading at least 3 significant digits on each parameters.

##### MSE Landscape

When investigating such kind of problem it is important to sketch the MSE Landscape to check the convergence towards global optimum.

Because your problem has a high dimensionality, it requires to project it a lot. I leave the toolbox to do it here:

```
partial = functools.partial(Kinetic.r, P.T)
vectorized = np.vectorize(partial, otypes=[np.ndarray])

def error(y):
    def wrapped(yhat):
        return np.log10(np.sum((y-yhat)**2)/y.size)
    return wrapped

N = 100
k1, k2, k4, k5, k0 = 5, 1e5, 50, 10, 100
k1l = np.logspace(-2, 2, N, base=10)
k2l = np.logspace(3, 7, N, base=10)
k4l = np.logspace(0, 4, N, base=10)
k5l = np.logspace(0, 4, N, base=10)
k0l = np.logspace(0, 4, N, base=10)

K1, K5 = np.meshgrid(k1l, k5l)

Rk = vectorized(K1, k2, k4, K5, k0)
mse = np.vectorize(error(R))
MSEk = mse(Rk)
```

And I'll take snapshot for some projections. For instance we see the non linear coupling between `k4` and `k0`:

[image]

And between `k1` and `k0`:

[image: enter code here]

Other projections are more regular:

[image]
[image]

By inspecting the MSE Landscape, most of the projections are sufficiently smooth, steep and convex to ensure stable convergence once we have enough points with acceptable errors.

But the coupling with parameters `k0` and `k4` introduce some extra complexity as it shapes canyons in the MSE Landscape that may slower or disturb the convergence. Anyway it seems an educated guess can prevent the algorithm to pass by those canyons.

#### Conclusions

Solving this kinetic requires two critical steps:

- Stable system solving with constraint (calculus + educated guess)
- Stable NLLS fit solving with constraint (TRF)

We can be confident, if your experiment follow the proposed model and experimental dataset contains enough data points with acceptable errors we should be able to regress kinetic constants from it using the above procedure.

#### Miscellaneous

Details of the procedure are shown in the note below:

[image]

##### System Abacus

To solve the non linear system, we can investigate abacus to visually assess the existence of the solution within the domain:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jlandercy for such a detailed answer. This is quite a new approach, especially analyzing the isopleth and MSE landscape part. I am aware of the convexity of the problem and the feasible region to look at my solution. However, not very clear on how to interpret the graphs you plotted. I am looking for some resources to get accustomed to these concepts better. If you have any recommendations, it will be great. Thank you!

Comment: Dear @SuyashSachinDamir, I have no precise reference to provide as this, this is more about 20 years of fitting experience. The principle is simple, compute the MSE wrt to your dataset and analyses geometrically. Guideline are the same as Maximum Likelihood Estimation (procedures are alike).

Comment: About integrating the temperature into your fit, you just need to adapt signature to add an extra dimension to your variable space (variable p may contains T as last dimension). But this will requires a lot more of points to make the fit converge (see dimensionality curse) and is somehow problematic as Langmuir model is isotherm and the selected model does not explicitly express Temperature dependencies. In my opinion, each dataset should be isotherm and you can reproduce the procedure for each explored temperature. Then you can regress your constants against temperature.

Comment: Hi, @jlandercy, your suggestions have been quite helpful to understand the model. I changed the problem statement a bit with the updated code (still the same idea, just solving it in a different way). I will appreciate any input regarding finalizing my K-parameters. Thanks!